# Problem with the Laurent series

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series, laurent-series

Find The Laurent series for the following function on the annulus $1<|z|<2$ :

$\displaystyle f(z)=\frac{2z}{z^2+z-2}$

---

My work :

$\displaystyle f(z)=\frac{2}{3} \left( \frac{1}{z-1}+\frac{2}{z+2}\right)=\frac{2}{3} \left(\sum _{k=-\infty }^{-1} z^k+\sum _{k=0}^{\infty } \left(-\frac{z}{2}\right)^k\right)  \ \ \  \ \ \ \ (\text{Geometric series})$

Ratio test can prove that it converges.

Please check my work before posting the solution.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The decomposition is ok and the development into Laurant series is ok too.

Comment: this means that it is correct ! :)

thanks